# Package a custom field on LiveChatTranscript object using 2gp

Tags: managed-package, appexchange, liveagent, 2gp, 2gp-ama

We are creating an AppExchange application where we need to package a custom field on the LiveChatTranscript object.

While creating a 2GP package, we are getting an error:

```
LiveChatTranscript.History__c: Entity 'LiveChatTranscript' not found.   
Here history is our custom field name.
```

We have already added the attribute in Project-scratch.Def.json:

```
"orgPreferenceSettings": {

"s1DesktopEnabled": true,

"IsLiveAgentEnabled": true }
```

We did some research and found that as per the below article, if you need Chat enabled in your scratch organization, please use the Developer edition.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000317632&type=1&mode=1

**Using 2GP, is it currently possible to package a custom field on the LiveChatTranscript object?**

**What is the best method to package a custom field on LiveChatTranscript with 2GP?**

Comment: can you share your full scratch-def.json file?

Comment: Sorry @MohithShrivastava, some how I missed my reply on your comment earlier. We did some R&D and in the answer we have added the details of the fix. Please let us know, if you have any comments/feedback on that.   Thanks Vivek for adding more tags to the question.

Answer (score 2):

We were able to package 2GP with a custom field on this **LiveChatTranscript** object by adding below attribute in scratch-def.json file.

```
"liveAgentSettings": {​​​​​​​​
      "enableLiveAgent": true
 }​​​​​​​​
```